# Select urls from soup object

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Please, how can I select leagues urls from [football-data.co.uk](https://www.football-data.co.uk/data.php). In next round I need that urls to download csv files with historical data.

My code:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://www.football-data.co.uk/data.php")
pgsource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pgsource, 'html.parser')
soup.select('a[href]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify which `a` elements you're looking for. In this case you can first use attributes to select the tables containing the links. And in each table you get the `href` you want:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(pgsource, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={"cellspacing":"2", "border":"0"})
for table in tables:
    for a in table.find_all('a', href=True):
        url = "https://www.football-data.co.uk/" + a['href']
        print(url)
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is perfect.